# Is there a way to have a local Google Cloud Composer / Airflow version 1?

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

I have an old Gcloud app written in Python that I can't upgrade to Composer 2 and Airflow 2. I tried to follow the [official guide](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/composer-2/run-local-airflow-environments), but Google does ***not*** allow you to download the old Composer 1 docker image with the command:

```
composer-dev create --from-image-version composer-1.20.12-airflow-1.10.15 LOCAL_ENVIRONMENT_NAME
```

Is there a way to debug locally an old Composer 1 DAG?

Comment: what is `composer-dev`?  `gcloud composer environments create --image-version composer-1.20.12-airflow-1.10.15 --location us-central1 foo` creates the environment just fine.

Answer (score 0):

According to @Oluwafemi Sule, you can create an environment by using `gcloud composer environments create --image-version composer-1.20.12-airflow-1.10.15 --location us-central1 foo`.

Unlike Composer 2, your project must have a VPC network (a network named "default" is normally present).

Please note that `version 1.10.14` was the latest version of Airflow 1.x as of September 2021. If there have been newer releases since then, you may want to use the latest stable version.

Posting this answer as a Community Wiki since this is the only possible workaround and for the benefit of the community that might encounter this use case in the future.

Please feel free to edit this answer for additional information and if there are other possible workarounds/direct solutions for this use case.